# Contagem de Checkbox enabled

Tags: javascript

Esse codigo faz a contagem de quantos `checkbox` fora marcados.
Como posso fazer para que ele não inclua na contagem os `checkbox disabled`

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
var contador = function() {
var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
$("#checkcount").text( n + (n === 1 ? " é" : " são") + " selecionados" );
};
contador(); 
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", contador );
}//]]> 
</script>


<input type="checkbox" name="check1" disabled value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" disabled value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="5">    
<div id="checkcount"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés disso

```
var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
```

Coloque isso:

```
var n = $( "input:enabled:checked" ).length;
```